# FFMPEG stream continuously changing file

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, rtsp, live-streaming

Is it possible to stream to RTSP/RTMP (ie output of ffmpeg), with an input file that is continously being updated (appended)?

Or to stream a list of files consecutively to the same RTSP/RTMP stream with no interruption?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are looking for is actually ffserver (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Streaming%20media%20with%20ffserver), which takes stream from ffmpeg and streams it to a client. Or did I get your question entirely wrong?

Comment: I need to stream a continously updated file to a wowza server, so it would be more of a client->server rather then server->client

Comment: did you get an answer for this?